# Update a table of sums to only contain one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table names bacteria, which contains sums. There is only one decimal point number in each column, the rest being nulls. Is there a way for me to update the table into removing the NULLS and merging all the decimals into one row? I need to keep the header so MAX doesn't work.

| phe | leu | ser | ile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.04248683 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 0.09419620 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 0.06114061 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 0.05847198 |

I tried update to set all the NULLs to 0 but still can't figure out a way to add the rows.

```
update bacteria set phe= 0 where phe is null
update bacteria set leu= 0 where  leu is null
update bacteria set ser= 0 where  ser is null
update bacteria set ile= 0 where  ile is null
```

I've also have tried different variations of

```
update bacteria set sum(phe).
```

Desired result is

| phe | leu | ser | ile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.04248683 | 0.09419620 | 0.06114061 | 0.05847198 |
|  |  |  |  |

Any help is appreciated as I'm still learning.

Comment: Please show us your desired results.

Comment: You cannot both update a table while also removing rows at the same time. If that is your goal, you will need to do that in two steps.

Comment: Updated with desired result and I don't mind doing it two steps, I just can't figure out how to.

Comment: *I need to keep the header so MAX doesn't work.*  Why can't you just use column [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))? i.e. `select max(phe) as phe, max(leu) as leu, max(ser) as ser, etc.... from bacteria `

Comment: Because I want to update the table so it looks cleaner. Right now, I have 20 columns with each column only containing one important decimal number, and 19 cells full of NULLs.

Comment: Updating means changing the column values. What you're describing involves updates and deletes.  While that's certainly possible, IMO if it's literally just 20 or so cols and 20 rows of hard coded values, it'd be easier to drop and recreate the table IMO

Comment: Are you doing this literally for the entire table or per a group of rows defined by columns you're not showing?

Comment: @Stu for the entire table, I only showed a snippet of the table here.

Comment: Then probably inserting an aggregated row into a new table, droping the original and renaming the new table would be the best approach. Or just create a *view* on your table?

Comment: @SOS this is actually the third table of data I created for this data from the original. I was trying to see if it could be done with creating a fourth table but I guess it's needed.

Comment: @user10902163 - If those tables are just failed attempts, drop them when you're finished, and the final table is in the "correct" format. BTW, you can use `#temp` tables and/or @ table variables for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table or update you table first add a new column, next an example of how you can do it if you want create a new table:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable
FROM (select MAX(phe) as phe, MAX(leu) as leu, MAX(ser) as ser, MAX(ile) as ile  from bacteria)
```